# Can I find the path of the executable running a python script from within the python script?

Tags: python, introspection

Is there a way to retreive the path of the executable that is running the current python script (from within the python script)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That should do what you want

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
'C:\\Python26\\python.exe'

>>> import os
>>> os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
'C:\\Python26'
```